# Meteor & mup - on linux server

Tags: linux, meteor, deployment

I have successfully installed a meteor app with MUP on my linux server my app files appear in

```
/opt/myapp
```

when I run **myapp start** I get

```
start: Job is already running: myapp
```

In my setting files I have

"ROOT_URL": "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx",

Wat url should the app resolve to? I have also tried

"ROOT_URL": "http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/myapp",

Comment: can you elaborate your question? what do you want to resolve?

Comment: should I be  able to see the app here "http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/myapp"

Comment: Do I need to create an entry in /etc/apache2/sites-available

Comment: no I've deployed my app so many times to EC2 ubuntu server, no need to do all those, just set root_url and deploy that's it. your app can be accessed at your domain name. Default port is 80

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use mup to stop/start, don't log into your server and use upstart manually. `ROOT_URL` should be `http://yourapp.com`, do not use subdirectories as it'll confuse your router.